# Potion Effects with Negative Levels

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

(Based on [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1fwqex/you_can_remove_player_hearts_using_the_health/))

Using external programs, it is possible to create an effect which actually **decreases** a players maximum health. This is achieved by using the health boost effect with a negative level, and is not possible without use of an external program.

However (with the use of an external program), I can only create the effect once. Is there any way I can summon the effect over and over?

I have a few theories on how this could be done, but none of them have worked.

1. Create a "negative" potion, and place it in a chest. Summon the item in the chest as a splash potion directly next to a player.
2. Remove the physics from a negative splash potion, leaving it suspended in mid-air. Copy and paste the entity on the ground nearby a player.

Normally, my strategy to solving this problem would be something along the lines of:

1. Clone a dispenser containing the potion above all players.
2. Activate the dispenser.
3. Break the dispenser, and the block activating it.` However, this will not always work, since players might be completely surrounded in blocks, or suffocating in a wall.

Comment: Which version are you asking this for? In 1.11, if the `Amplifier` tag is below 0, the game will instead use 0 for the amplifier rather than the negative number (more details [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/5lybx9/why_even_remove_negative_amplifiers/dbzh8g6/).

Comment: @Skylinerw I am using 1.11.2. Does that change obsolete this?

Comment: Unfortunately it does. You could still use attribute modifiers to change `generic.maxHealth`, but it's quite different than potions (since it requires the player to wear something)